# Adyen Customcard component is not working sometimes in React

Tags: html, reactjs, adyen

I am using adyen payment gateway's customcard component in my React JS project. When there are some dom updates in my parent component Adyen secure fields will not work correctly. I don't know why. Please refer the attached screenshots for reference. Is there any call back method to handle such kind of error or Is there any solution to this issue.
[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like there is an error being thrown regarding the originKey.  Are you passing that through as a prop? also, would you mind sharing the component code as well as where you initialize the checkout?

Comment: Have you configured the component with either origin key or client key? If not can you set up the [client key](https://docs.adyen.com/development-resources/client-side-authentication). Here is an example React + adyen usage (https://github.com/adyen-examples/adyen-react-online-payments) please let me know if the issue persists

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is caused by the fact that you are trying to initialize the Adyen component more than once. This is a common problem especially when people are using Vue or React, make sure not to re-render the DOM element.